# How would I shorten this discord.js code to check for multiple permissions if an user has it?

Tags: discord.js

```js
if(message.member.hasPermission("SEND_MESSAGES")){
      for(i=0;i<config.commands.SEND_MESSAGES.length;i++){
        helpArray.push(config.commands.SEND_MESSAGES[i]);
      };
    };
    if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")){
      for(i=0;i<config.commands.MANAGE_MESSAGES.length;i++){
        helpArray.push(config.commands.MANAGE_MESSAGES[i]);
      };
    };
    if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")){
      for(i=0;i<config.commands.MANAGE_CHANNELS.length;i++){
        helpArray.push(config.commands.MANAGE_CHANNELS[i]);
      };
    };
    if(message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")){
      for(i=0;i<config.commands.KICK_MEMBERS.length;i++){
        helpArray.push(config.commands.KICK_MEMBERS[i]);
      };
    };
    if(message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")){
      for(i=0;i<config.commands.BAN_MEMBERS.length;i++){
        helpArray.push(config.commands.BAN_MEMBERS[i]);
      };
    };
    if(config.whitelist.botowners.includes(message.author.id)){
      for(i=0;i<config.commands.whitelist.botowners.length;i++){
        helpArray.push(config.commands.whitelist.botowners[i]);
      };
    };
    var help_embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(config.embed.title)
    .setColor(config.embed.color)
    .setFooter(config.embed.footer, client.user.displayAvatarURL)
    .setDescription(helpArray.join('\n'));
    message.channel.send(help_embed);
  }
```

Basically config.commands.permission is an array with all the commands and information for that permission. How could i shorten this code? Or isn't that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by using another `for` loop *(see: [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of))* to iterate over each permission, you can shorten and clean up your code.

```js
for (let perm of config.commands) {
  // Handle the outlier permission...
  if (perm === 'whitelist' && config.whitelist.botowners.includes(message.author.id)) {
    for (let cmd of config.commands.whitelist.botowners) helpArray.push(cmd);
    continue;
  }

  if (message.member.hasPermission(perm)) {
    for (let cmd of config.commands[perm]) helpArray.push(cmd);
  }
}
```